# Is it possible to claim my Elsevier submitted papers on my ORCID publication list?

Tags: paper-submission, elsevier, digital-researcher-id

Elsevier submission portals (normally) have a link to your Orcid number. Regarding this, is it possible to add your submitted papers to Orcid, directly by a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No! Unless you uploaded a copy of your submitted paper to public preprint server like PeerJ Preprints, ArXiv or BioRxiv. If you uploaded a public preprint you can add that to your ORCID profile.

---

**Extra note:** About your published works, as you know, you can add your publications from any publisher to your ORCID profile (after you sign-in to your ORCID account) by clicking on "Add Works".

More information is given here: http://orcid.org/blog/2013/12/05/i-claimed-my-orcid-id-now-what

I'd recommend the CrossRef Metadata Search as often the easiest method of importing one's publications, provided those publications have a registered DOI.

Comment: Thanks; however, my question is about my submitted papers which have not been published yet, but are registered in Elsevier.

Comment: well, the answer is no then. Unless you uploaded a copy of your submitted paper to public preprint server like PeerJ Preprints, ArXiv or BioRxiv. If you uploaded a public preprint you can add that to your ORCID profile.

Comment: @rmounc, would you kindly revise your answer by putting your comment into the answer text?

Comment: @hossayni: If you make a fundamental edit to a post that implements comments of the poster, indicate this in the edit summary. Otherwise reviewers are likely to reject that edit as too drastic.

Comment: I have found out that both Scopus and Web of Science insist on importing a new version of my papers, even if one exists already in Orcid. :( Oh, if only there was a unique identifier for every publication to avoid duplicates, something like a digital object identifier...

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I agree; but because of a misunderstanding the main body did not contain my answer and had only some useful information for society.
Therefore, I saw that it deserved to be the accepted answer only if the main answer comes to first.

Comment: @hossayni: I do not complain about the edit (in fact, [I approved it](http://academia.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/20292)), I rather wanted to advice you to write something in the edit summary along the lines of: *Implementing additions as per the author’s comments.* (at least for future edits of this sort).

Comment: Elsevier has a bad reputation in science, don't publish with them, they are not worth it. Take a look [here](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/information-culture/is-elsevier-really-for-science-or-just-for-profit/) .